# get column of database as string in CI

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

```
group     number
-------  -------------
grp1    01714586236
grp2    01924586236
grp1    01682659834
grp1    018823453468
grp2    01985345098
```

---

I want the all numbers of column `number` where `group`='grp1' as

```
(01714586236,01682659834,018823453468,......)
```

in code igniter, plz share the answer by posting all of controller, model & view

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: "Posting all of controller, model & view"...is there anything else you need? Your house painted maybe?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [**`GROUP_CONCAT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)  function, like so:

```
SELECT
  `group`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(`number` SEPARATOR ',')
FROM Table
WHERE `group` = 'grp1' 
GROUP BY `group`;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86722/2)

This will give you:

```
| GROUP |                          THEGROUP |
---------------------------------------------
|  grp1 | 1714586236,1682659834,18823453468 |
```